# main.lua: attempt to index upvalue 'bricks' (a function value)

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

Got this error while transitioning from "main menu" to the game screen. On click of "Play" , main-menu disappears and level 1 appears. For this level, I have added bricks using displayGroup.
Getting error at line **bricks:toFront();** If I remove this line/ place somewhere else, then getting error at **bricks.insert(bricks, brick)**

```
playButton:addEventListener("tap", loadGame);

function loadGame(event)
    if event.target.name  == "playbutton" then
        transition.to(menuScreenGrp, {time = 0, alpha = 0, onComplete = addGameScreen});
        playBtn:removeEventListener("tap", loadGame);
    end
end

function addGameScreen()
   -- code for displaying background and other stuff
   loadLevel1();
end

function loadLevel1()

    currentLevel = 1;
    bricks:toFront();  -- Got error here

    for row = 0, numOfRows - 1 do
    for column = 0, numOfColumns - 1 do

      --logic to position bricks
      physics.addBody(brick, "static", {density = 1, friction = 0, bounce = 0})
      bricks.insert(bricks, brick)

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution quickly.

In the reference document, group was initialized as local variable as :

```
local bricks = display.newGroup();
```

So when I was trying to access it inside function, it was giving the error.

Solution is I just declared the variable and then initialized it inside function.